# How do I properly revoke a grant using the tapkey management api?

Tags: tapkey

I'm using the `TapKey` management `API` to manage all my grants, locks etc. All calls to the `API` are working fine. However, when I try to `POST` to revoke a grant, it fails with a `404` status. Suggesting that the grant does not exist. But when I `GET` a list of all grants, I can see the grant being active and present. Is my `url` wrong? Or is my `json` containing the dryRun boolean wrong? Or anything else?

**My URL:**

```
https://my.tapkey.com/api/v1/owners/{ownerID}/Grants/{grantID}/Revoke
```

**My json body:**

```
{
   "dryRun": false
}
```

Regards,

Stan

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](https://developers.tapkey.io/api/grants/#revoke-grant) the `dryRun` parameter should be sent as a query param, rather than in the request body.

Best,
Markus

Comment: Ok. I didn't see that :facepalm: So sometimes data is in the querystring and sometimes in the body. I should have looked better. Thanks for the answer